# "Pattern match" doesn't work for Int clause (branch)

Tags: kotlin

I have this piece of code in Kotlin (which I started learning):

```
package io.shido.learning

import java.time.Instant

fun typeCheck(any: Any): Any = when (any) {
  (any is Int && any < 10) -> "(small) integer"
  is Int -> "integer"
  is Double -> "double"
  is String -> "string"
  else -> "another Any"
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  println("type check for: 5 (${typeCheck(5)})")
  println("type check for: 20 (${typeCheck(20)})")
  println("type check for: 56.0 (${typeCheck(56.0)})")
  println("type check for: \"a string\" (${typeCheck("a string")})")
  println("type check for: Instant (${typeCheck(Instant.now())})")
}
```

...so I was expecting that `typeCheck(5)` returned `(small) integer` and not `integer` as it currently does.

Does anyone has any insights? The first branch is `true` indeed for `5`.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you pass an argument, `when` checks if argument matches values in branches, and 5 not matches calculated `true` in first branch. So basically you can fix your code this way:

```
fun typeCheck(any: Any): Any = when {
    (any is Int && any < 10) -> "(small) integer"
    any is Int -> "integer"
    any is Double -> "double"
    any is String -> "string"
    else -> "another Any"
}
```

or

```
fun typeCheck(any: Any): Any = when (any) {
    in 0..10 -> "(small) integer"
    is Int -> "integer"
    is Double -> "double"
    is String -> "string"
    else -> "another Any"
}
```

See [When Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression)

Comment: I'm using IDEA and when I evaluate the expression `(any is Int && any < 10)` for `5` it's `true`; on the other hand, if I delete the `any` from the `when` expression it works, but I have to repeat `any` every single time in the branches (which is something I was trying to avoid by using `when (any)`).

Comment: ...and it gets more "interesting"; if I just add `when (any)` to your first solution...nothing works saying that it's `another Any` for *any* value! So it looks like the `any` parameter and the `any` in the `when` is "not the same"...that cannot be true.

Comment: For sure `(any is Int && any < 10)` for `5` is `true`, but `true` doesn't match `5`, so first branch doesn't evaluate.

Comment: It's doesn't work because `when (foo) {}` and `when {}` have different semantics. This semantics described well in documentation.

Comment: Note that checking if a value of `Any` type is in the range `0..10` will iterate the values of the range until an equal value is found.